# c++ use derived class in std::shared_ptr<baseclass>

Tags: c++11, shared-ptr

I have the following structure:

```
class A 
{
   A(const A&) {...}
   virtual int member() = 0;
   virtual ~A() {}; 
}

class B : public A 
{ 
   virtual int member(){... }  
   virtual ~B(){}
}

class C : public A 
{
   virtual int member(){... }  
   virtual ~C(){}
}
```

And use `std::shared_ptr<A>` as return type of my factory.

```
std::shared_prt<A> Factory::get(params...)
{
   ...

   return std::make_shared<B>(params);
}

std::shared_ptr<A> Aptr = Factory::get(params...)
```

Now I try to pass it to an external method:

```
boost::iostreams::filtering_istream

void push( const T& t,
           std::streamsize buffer_size = default value,
           std::streamsize pback_size = default value );
```

this call fails at compile time because some_external_function tries to call the pure `member()` of A and not of B.

concept_adapter.hpp:122: Error:cannot declare field 'boost::iostreams::detail::concept_adapter::t_' to be of abstract type 'A'

Comment: What is the prototype of `some_external_function`? Does it get parameter by value? You should get it either by reference or pointer if you want polymorphism to work.

Comment: *How* and *when* does it fail? Compile time? Run time? Please provide more details, including compiler errors/warnings (if there are any) or debugger backtraces.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, yes you're right, I removed my comment

Comment: Without the declaration of `some_external_function` and the exact details of the failure this question is off-topic and should be closed, please provide the information requested by Joachim Pileborg in the comment above.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I added the requested information

Comment: The error message does not support your statement that "`some_external_function` tries to call the pure `member()` of `A`". It would appear that `A` does not satisfy a requirement of the Boost code to which you are passing it - most like copy constructibility. Indeed, the [documentation of `boost::iostreams::filtering_istream::push`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/filtering_stream.html#policy_push) requires the first argument to be CopyConstructible.

Comment: A is copyable so this should not be the source of the problem

Comment: maybe try with boost::shared_ptr<T> instead

Comment: An abstract class is not copyable. Even if A was copyable, it would be a problem because *you should not copy a polymorphic object* anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *have* to use the PImpl idiom here.

The `push` method requires that the first argument is copy constructible. Which means that it is copied somewhere deep inside the guts of Boost. No good, because you cannot copy a polymorphic object, it will be sliced.

The solution is to have a non-polymorphic class `APimpl` that holds a pointer (shared, unique or raw, you decide) to `A`, and forwards calls to that pointer. It can be copied freely with no ill effects of slicing.

```
class APimpl
{
   public:
     APimpl(std::shared_ptr<A> a) : p_a(a) {}
     // compiler-generated copy ctor and assignment are OK here
     void method() { p_a->method(); }
   private:
     std::shared_ptr<A> p_a; 
};
```

You may need to have a `clone` method in `A` and use it when copying `APimpl`, or have an `A` shared between many instances of `APimpl`. Which one you want depends on what `A` does. My example demonstrates the second case.